# Find Wordpress sites hosted by specific hosting provider

Tags: looking-for-hosting

I'm looking to potentially upgrade my Wordpress hosting to improve performance.  I've read through [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements).  However, before moving my site to a new provider, I'd like to "test" the hosts' performance prior to signing up.

I know that it's possible to lookup who hosts a particular domain, but are there any tricks to doing this in reverse?  I.e., is it possible to look up what domains are using WordPress hosted by a particular hosting provider?

Alternatively, is there a way to see what IP address blocks a web host "owns"?  If I knew the address blocks, I could look at what domains where hosted by IP address.

Comment: Have you asked the host for a list of customers or for testimonials from current customers?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, yes I actually did ask for a list of customer websites using WP from the one vendor I was evaluating.  They claim the information is confidential and violates company policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way would be to get a list of domains and then see what happens if you try to load example.com/wp-config.php - if the site uses WP it should be blank, if not there will be an error 404.

If you have some coding skills, you could write a script that looped through the domains trying to load wp-config.php and displayed the result or wrote the output to a file or emailed you or whatever.